# Where are the Windows Phone APIs in Windows XAML Universal Portable Library?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a library for Windows Phone 8.0 and Windows 8 and thought to make the same to support the Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 Universal applications.

But soon as I tried to port my code in a Universal XAML library or even when trying some APIs in a Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Application that is created using the template I've seen that are missing, for example,

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Info;
using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;
```

Or I was using the PhoneApplicationFrame class, RootFrame in the App.xaml.cs file that is now too changed dramatically.

Where do I find these namespaces to get information related to the device?

Answer (score 4):

Here are the Windows Runtime APIs equivalents of the APIs you mentioned:

- [Devices (`Windows.Devices.*`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx#devices)
- [Networking (`Windows.Networking.*`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx#networking)

Please not that you won't have 1:1 equivalent. You'll have access to new functionality but other will be missing (example : the Battery API).

About the changes in the `PhoneApplicationFrame`, you shouldn't try to fit the Silverlight model (navigation, frame system...) into the new Universal one. Instead, I recommend to use the default project template and use that model (with the Helper classes like `NavigationHelper` and `SuspensionManger`).

EDIT (thanks @Romasz): Here is an MSDN page that should help you [Migrating your Windows Phone 8 app to a Windows Runtime XAML app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn642486%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: (+1) As you have been faster ;) - just a referrence from my answer: [Windows Runtime in comparison to WP8.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn642486%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) - not every feature/namespace is available, some have its equivalent, but some not.

Comment: Thank you both of you, these kind of breaking changes, OMG! I don't need the PhoneApplicationFrame for navigation but instead I was previously registering in the PhoneApplicationFrame.OrientationChanged event to get the current orientation.