# Equivalent windows 10 class of PhoneApplicationFrame, PhoneApplicationPage and PhoneApplicationService

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am migrating windows phone 8 project to windows 10 and found certain classes and namespaces get changed.

What is equivalent windows 10 class of following windows 8 classes.

> Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationService
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage

Comment: There is no 1:1 equivalent for these classes. Here is a [good explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23823819/815938).